# How to completely disable screensaver / turning off screen on Ubuntu MATE 20.04?

Tags: display, settings, screensaver, ubuntu-mate

On Ubuntu MATE 20.04, which I use as a live TV laptop OS, there seems to be a problem with some settings, upon which the screensaver is run or the screen turns off; I don't know if both apply, or which one.

What is the goal:

- To disable the screensaver forever or generally leave the screen on all the time.
- I normally `ssh` to this machine, so I prefer script or command solutions.

What I did already: I looked everywhere in the standard settings, but no clue, nor any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Autostart script solution

Before you start reading, make sure, that in your Power Management preferences the display is set to Never to be put to sleep when inactive.

---

So, I did a lot of digging, and thanks to the official forum ([source link](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-can-i-turn-the-screensaver-powersavings-off/5414/2)) I got my answer:

---

Place the below script to this location:

```sh
~/.config/autostart/
```

Script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10 && xset -dpms s off s noblank s 0 0 s noexpose
```

Obviously, you can name it to your liking, e.g. `disable_screensaver` and you need to `chmod 775` it.

Note, that the `sleep 10` can be adjusted to how fast your desktop loads, mine is slow, so...